# Experiencing font size issues for surface pros in java

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have an application that works perfectly on screens apart from the surface pro tablets, these causes the font to be huge and unable to read, this is the current code, personally didn't write this but any ideas of a fix? would also like to understand why you times the screen res and divide?

```
 int fontSize = (int) Math.round(Float.parseFloat(properties.get("FontSize").toString()) * screenRes / 75.0);
```

**Edit**

It seems to be with the DPI. Most monitors are 96, however surface pros start from 144 DPI. I can implement an if statement to check if the screen res is above say 140, however i feel this isn't the correct way.

**Update**

Will keep you updated of my findings, it seems to be java swing doesn't actually support high DPI or work well with high DPI. Oracle seem to prefer users to use JavaFX, Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Swing is not DPI aware and JavaFX is! Have a look at this (Blogpost) [http://news.kynosarges.org/2013/08/09/javafx-dpi-scaling/].